# Prove that the critical point of the function is really a local minimum under a constraint.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here's the thing:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued $C^{\infty}$ functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2|f\left(x,y\right)=0\right\}$. Suppose that at some point $p=\left(a,b\right)\in S$, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(p\right)=-1, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(p\right)=2, \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\left(p\right)=3, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\left(p\right)=-6$, and
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(p)& \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(p)\\
> \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(p) & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(p)\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1&3\\
> 3&0\\
> \end{bmatrix},
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(p)& \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial y}(p)\\
> \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y \partial x}(p) & \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}(p)\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 3&-1\\
> -1&2\\
> \end{bmatrix}.
> \end{equation}
>   Show that there exists $R>0$ such that $g\left(p\right)<g\left(q\right)$ for $q\in S\cap \left\{\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2|\left(x-a\right)^2+\left(y-b\right)^2<R^2\right\}$.

My thoughts:

I consider the function $h=g+3f$, and have $\nabla{h}\left(p\right)=\nabla g\left(p\right)+3\nabla f\left(p\right)=0$. Therefore, I get $p$ is a **critical** point by Lagarange Multipier Method. But I don't know how to prove $p$ is **really** a minimum point. By the way, I also observe 
\begin{equation}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2}(p)& \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x \partial y}(p)\\
\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y \partial x}(p) & \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y^2}(p)\\
\end{bmatrix}
=\det
\begin{bmatrix}
6&8\\
8&2\\
\end{bmatrix}
=-52<0,
\end{equation}
but I don't know whether it would be helpful.

What I'm struggling with:

How to prove $p$ is really a local minimum point?

I need your help. Could you give me some hints? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You are close with the determinant of the second derivative (Hessian) matrix. Do you know what the "Hessian criterion" for determining local extrema is?

Comment: @JG123 - I know and this determinant is negative; hence $p$ is a saddle point for $h$.